# NoReverseMatch at /<url>

Tags: django

Django 1.7.0 beta 4
Python 2.7.9

I'm currently trying to use Django's CBVs to create modals. I had no problem with the ListView, but I'm stuck when trying to call my UpdateView using url tags.
I'm getting the following error:

> NoReverseMatch at /dashboard_usuario_list/
>   Reverse for 'dashboard_usuario_edit' with arguments '(u'test2',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['dashboard_usuario_edit/(?Pd+)/?$']

views.py:

```
class UserProfileListView(ListView):
    model = UserProfile
    template_name = 'dashboard_usuario_list.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return UserProfile.objects.all()

class UserProfileUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = UserProfile
    form_class = UserProfileForm
    template_name = 'dashboard_usuario_edit.html'

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.username = kwargs['username']
        return super(UserProfileUpdateView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """
        If the form is valid, redirect to the supplied URL.
        """
        form.save()
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(username = self.username)
        return HttpResponse(render_to_string('dashboard_usuario.html', {'username':user_profile}))


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserProfileUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

url.py:

```
url(r'^dashboard_usuario_list/', views.UserProfileListView.as_view(), name = 'dashboard_usuario_list'),
url(r'^dashboard_usuario_edit/(?P<username>d+)/?$', views.UserProfileUpdateView.as_view(), name = 'dashboard_usuario_edit'),
```

dashboard_usuario_list.html:
`<a href="{% url 'dashboard_usuario_edit' user.user.username %}"></a>`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url for `dashboard_usuario_edit` has regex pattern to accept only integers `\d+` as `username`, which is wrong, username can consist of alpha numeric characters, so your pattern should be:

```
url(r'^dashboard_usuario_edit/(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/?$', views.UserProfileUpdateView.as_view(), name = 'dashboard_usuario_edit'),
```